# Customising Okular Text-to-Speech

Tags: text-to-speech, okular

My computer details:

- OS:                Kubuntu 20.04
- Okular:            1.9.3
- Speech dispatcher: 0.9.1
- I am using pico as the tts engine, but cannot find its version.

I want to customise some aspects of Okular's text-to-speech (tts) behaviour. Here are a few examples.

**Number**

- Text:             warehouse no. 4
- Generated speech: warehouse no {pause for period} four
- Desired speech:   warehouse number four

**Square Brackets**

- Text:             [...]
- Generated speech: left square bracket {long pause for three periods} right square bracket
- Desired speech:   {ignore this without speaking}

How can I achieve this? Where can I do the configuration, in Okular or in speech-dispatcher?

Thanks for the help

Johan